# how to use c get size of a file which is created using dd command

Tags: c, linux, file-io, dd

i create a file using dd command like this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=1g.dd bs=1M count=512 seek=512
```

when i run command `ls 1g.dd`, its size is 1G, run `du 1g.dd`, it's 512M.

there is a `struct stat` in c library to read file size, but it can only read out that 1G size, now how can i get that 512M size which is the real size of that file?

now the only way i know is to parse shell command `du`'s output. can i read out the size from the file directly?

Comment: BTW if you do a du --apparent-size you'll get the same 1G result that ls was reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `st_blocks` member of `struct stat` for that, it tells you how many 512 byte blocks (this is valid on Linux, could be different on other OSes, and could depend on the filesystem) have been allocated to the file.

Comment: it works, thanks a lot! one more thing, why 512, what's `st_blksize` used for?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: no, st_blksize isn't related to that. See  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html: "There is no correlation between values of the st_blocks and st_blksize, and the f_bsize (from <sys/statvfs.h>) structure members."

Comment: `st_blksize` is the "A file system-specific preferred I/O block size 
for this object." (see link in previous comment) It is not related to the size of the file.